# Which browsers support intent scheme URL ("intent:mydata1#Intent;action=myaction1;type=text/plain;end";)

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

Which browsers support intent scheme URL like `"intent://" + data + "#Intent;scheme=" + scheme + ";package=" + package_name + ";S.browser_fallback_url=" + store_link_encoded + ";S.market_referrer=" + referrer + ";end"`